# C# IComparable with one parent and 2 children

Tags: c#, icomparable

Well, I have a class Human that implement `IComparable<Human>`

Then I have two more classes that inherit from Human Child:Human and Cousin:Human

The Parent class has a property AGE that has in the getter a call to a function getAge() which is abstract.

I have a List of Humans and when I display them in a datagrid every age is calculated properly.

I want to sort the list using age as attribute so I make the Human abstract class to implement Icomparable and then the method like this.

```
public int CompareTo(Human other)
{
     return this.age.CompareTo(other.age);
}
```

I invoke the `list.sort()` method in the ASP like this

```
List<Human> hlist = instance.humanlist;
hlist.Sort();
tblHumans.DataSource = hlist;
tblHumans.DataBind();
```

The page loads with all the data but the items are not ordered by age, it seems ordered by position in the list.

My tblHumans is

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="tblHumans" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

In the Parent class the attribute AGE is like this

```
public int Age
{
    get
    {
        return getAge();
    }

    set
    {
        age = getAge();
    }
}
```

getAge() is an abstract method that my child classes overrides

The calculation is returns values correctly, when the table is rendered every single value is there with the right results.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it doesn't make sense to make `Child` and `Cousin` inherit from `Human`... "child" and "cousin" are relationships, not types of human.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your `CompareTo` method to ensure that it's called?

Comment: Your question lacks info about what type tblHumans is of. Most probably, DataSource property ignores ordering unless you use some specific collection, for example, BindingList.

Comment: I make a breakpoint in the Human compareTo but the age seems to be always in 0, wich is weird because in the list of humans the age is propertly calculated, I will be checking on that.

Comment: @Alexev please show the code for the `age` property

Comment: Your setter is wrong. It should be `= value;`.

Comment: I would be wary of using `IComparable` for this. What happens when someone wants to sort humans by name? `IComparable` is best used for value types with a single well-defined ordering. For example, the .NET struct `BigInteger` implements this because integers have a single well-known ordering. For cases where you want to sort based upon attributes of a complex object, you are better off either using lambdas (with `List.Sort` or LINQ's `OrderBy`) or by implementing an `IComparer` (e.g. `HumanAgeComparer`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fix it

thank you all for the time you took reading and answering this question.

At last I made this:

1) set again the age property and field with normal getter and setter
2) in the child class when I override the getAge method I force set the age too, so, when the compareTo is called in the sort method of the list the age property is populated so it is shown in the table.

I know it is not 'the best practic' but It has to be made this way because in this program I cannot use 'complex' data models (not even a database, but dont worry is not for a production system)

Thanks all again

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

```
public int CompareTo(Human other)
{
     return this.Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
}
```

(`Age`, not `age`)

#### Longer answer

Your implementation of the `Age` property is broken. You have an `age` field, but its value is not used by the getter (which just calls `getAge()`). And the setter ignores the implicit `value` argument, so it just assigns `age` to the result of `getAge()`. So, while the setter hasn't been called, `age` isn't initialized and its value is 0. You probably shouldn't have a setter at all, and you should remove the `age` field, since the value of `Age` is only decided by the implementation of `getAge()`.

Comment: If I remove the age field how can I use it in the grid? the only reason I put the age property is because i need to sort it by it

Comment: Well, actually that worked with a sligth difference, I just made this method    public int CompareTo(Human other)
        {         
            return this.getAge().CompareTo(other.getAge());
        }  now I need to figure out how to show that data on the grid because it is not longer on the object

Comment: @Alexev you should compare by the property (`Age`), not the field (`age`). The field is an implementation detail, and from the code you posted, you're not really using it. Implementations of `getAge()` may use a field to store the value, but you don't need to care about this when comparing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your problem like this,

```
List<Human> hlist = instance.humanlist;
hlist.Sort();

// What is the order of the elements here, have they been sorted as you expect?    

tblHumans.DataSource = hlist;
tblHumans.DataBind();
```

If the list is sorted as you expect, then the problem is with the grid, if not, then you haven't implemented `IComparable` or the `Age` property properly. Which is it?